# How can these classes be associated?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am having a Taxi that transports Person and this Transportation is covered by an Agreement. How can these 4 classes be associated in a UML Diagram?

I have tried to associate Person and Taxi. But how can I show that this is a Transportation that is then covered by the Agreement?

Comment: You could use an association class for Transportation and have a separate class for Agreement, associated with Transportation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it permitted, though, to associate an association class with another class? I searched for this yesterday, but could not find an answer (it was what I initially thought too, but I had many doubts).

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What should hinder you?

Comment: Yes, association class has all capabilities of association and of a class at the same time. On the other hand is Transportation - Agreement 1-1 relationship or can there be many Transportations under single Agreement?

Comment: As far as UML is concerned, it is allowed to have many Transportations under single Agreement. Whether this is correct in your case, I don't know. You should ask a subject matter expert.

Comment: still no diagram in an answer ? _a picture is worth a thousand words_ ;-)

Comment: An Agreement is supposed to cover just one Transportation (and vice versa), so it is a 1-1 relationship in this case.
(Thank you all for giving me an insight into association classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an association class called Transportation for the Taxi-Person association. Agreement could be a separate class, associated with Transportation.
It is allowed to associate an association class with another class.